# Random truncation with poisson process

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

Suppose, a Poisson process is observed in fixed time intervals, e.g. we record the output of a Geiger counter during a time interval $\Delta t$ started randomly. The decay rate is much larger than this time interval, so
$$T \ll \frac1\lambda$$
Now, I know that for a non-truncated observations, the time difference between two consecutive events follows an exponential distribution
$$p(\delta t) = \frac1\lambda e^{-\lambda \delta t} $$

For a fixed truncation, I also know that the probability density looks the same, just truncated and normalized.

Now, the problem I can't figure out is: The truncation is random. If the first event is in the beginning of our measure period, then it is truncated at $\delta t \lesssim T$. But if the first event of a period is near the end, it is truncated much more, since there is less time in which a second event might occur.

I know, I could obtain $\lambda$ from the number of events per $T$, or by concatenation of several independent measurements, even though they are not consequent. But what distribution would $\delta t$ follow in that case and could one determine $\lambda$ from such a measurement?

Edit: My intuition was that it does not change, yet neither real life measurements, nor the result from a random number generator agree with that here. To test this, I ran the following code:

Generate time stamps with a difference sampled from $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $\lambda \in (1, 5, 10)$

```
ts1 = np.cumsum(np.random.exponential(1,1000000))
ts5 = np.cumsum(np.random.exponential(5,1000000))
ts10 = np.cumsum(np.random.exponential(10,1000000))
```

Loop over windows of length 1 and count the number of events in each time window, as well as the time difference if more than one event exists:

```
deltaT1 = []
deltaT5 = []
deltaT10 = []
nevents1 = []
nevents5 = []
nevents10 = []

for i in range(len(ts1)):
    n1 = len(ts1[(ts1>i)&(ts1<(1+i))])
    n5 = len(ts5[(ts5>i)&(ts5<(i+1))])
    n10 = len(ts10[(ts10>i)&(ts10<(i+1))])
    nevents1.append(n1)
    nevents5.append(n5)
    nevents10.append(n10)
    while n1>1:
        deltaT1.append((ts1[(ts1>i) & (ts1<(1+i))][n1-1]- ts1[(ts1>i) & (ts1<(1+i))][n1-2]))
        n1-=1
    while n5>1:
        deltaT5.append((ts5[(ts5>i) & (ts5<(1+i))][n5-1]- ts5[(ts5>i) & (ts5<(1+i))][n5-2]))
        n5-=1
    while n10>1:
        deltaT10.append((ts10[(ts10>i) & (ts10<(1+i))][n10-1]- ts10[(ts10>i) & (ts10<(1+i))][n10-2]))
        n10-=1
```

The mean number of events does follow a Poisson distribution with mean $1/\lambda$:

```
print(np.mean(nevents1), np.mean(nevents5), np.mean(nevents10))
Output: 1.0 0.200107 0.099953
```

However, the mean values of the different `deltaT` surprise me:

```
print(np.mean(deltaT1), np.mean(deltaT5), np.mean(deltaT10))
Output: 0.28116357748602905 0.32065439473099616 0.32102902250398857
```

And as a [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91X55.png) it does not seem follow an exponential pdf.
The code for the histograms:

```
plt.hist(deltaT1, bins=10, range=(0,1), label="$\lambda=1$", log=True, histtype="step")
plt.hist(deltaT5, bins=10, range=(0,1), label="$\lambda=5$", histtype="step", log=True)
plt.hist(deltaT10, bins=10, range=(0,1), histtype="step", log=True, label="$\lambda=10$")
plt.xlabel("$\delta t$ between consequent events within intervals of 1")
plt.legend()
```

Comment: What do you mean by “truncation” here? You stop the observing the Poisson process at a fixed time or random time?

Comment: I stop observing at a fixed time, but that time relative to an event is random. But I suppose I have to treat it as random if I am interested in the time between signals.

Comment: @angryavian The way I tried to denote it, $T$ is a fixed time interval. Let's say one second. I record a large number of these intervals of a Poisson process with a rate that is much smaller than 1 Hz. The random variable I am interested is the time between consecutive events within the same, fixed one-second interval.

Comment: I don’t understand how this differs from the standard setting. If you observe a Poisson process over any finite, non random interval $(0,t]$ then the waiting times between arrivals during this time interval are exponentially distributed with mean $1/\lambda$, you already know this, of course. If you look at a small portion of this interval, say $(0, \delta t]$ where $0<\delta<1$, the same thing is true. The distribution of the waiting time between arrivals of a Poisson process is independent of the length of the time interval that the process is observed in, it only depends on the mean rate.

Comment: @NapD.Lover I have added code and the results of random number generation to make more clear what I am trying to do and show the (to me) unexpected result.

Comment: Something is strange with your $n1,n5$ etc. If the waiting times $W_i \sim \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ have mean $1/\lambda$ then $N_t$ should have mean $\lambda t$. $\lambda$ is the rate of events per time-unit so $1/\lambda$ has units of time and $\lambda t$ is mean number of events. Since you are getting means of $1/\lambda$ for your Poisson process I don’t think it is generated correctly. I’ll see if I can write down mathematically what is going on and different code to verify that the waiting times over any subinterval follow the exponential, when I get time later today.

Comment: I am sorry, I think, I confused $\lambda$ with $\beta$ that is the parameter in the numpy function.
```
[ins] In [1]: np.random.exponential(10,3)
Out[1]: array([ 1.90274036, 13.68724977, 12.39802266])
```
So I actually generated $\lambda \in (1, 1/5, 1/10)$.

Comment: ah I see you are correct. That function uses the parameterization $\beta^{-1} e^{-x/\beta}$. I will still look into this in the afternoon today and see what I can find.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Thank you

Comment: So I looked into this with an alternative simulation, which is quite common. Conditional on $N_t=n$ then the arrival times are the order statistics of $n$ RVs with distribution $\mathcal{U}(0,t)$. So we can simulate the arrival times by generating a single random $n\sim Pois(\lambda t)$ and then sorting $n$ uniforms from $(0,t)$. Then take a small portion $(0,\delta) \subset (0,t)$, compute the waiting times by differencing, take their mean, and we recover $1/\lambda$ when $t$ (or rather $\lambda t$) is large, so the LLN will work for sample averages. I can write this up if you’re interested.